# How do I determine how much water is in my water heater's tank?

Tags: water-heater

We are in S. Texas experiencing record breaking cold weather. Have had hot water since this began. Today, third day into double digit temps, city announced broken water pipes and water boil notice. Water pressure out of tap is almost nonexistent. No water at all out of hot taps. Turn off heater?   I know nothing about hot water heaters. Just don’t want it to explode if it contains no water and continues to heat empty. Gas heater. Below freezing weather still in forecast. Heater located in garage. How does one know how much water is in the tank?

Comment: In the days of the telegraph or newspaper ads where one paid by the word, leaving words out was a reasonable thing to do. These days, words are cheap (in more ways than one), so using complete sentences, while not absolutely _necessary_ sure does make your question easier to read.

Comment: Also, I edited the title to make it match the question you asked in the body of your question. If you actually want to know whether you should drain the tank, feel free to [edit] again, change the title, and ask about that, instead. Or, feel free to ask a second question about draining the tank.

Comment: Make sure heater is off, then can drain if worried about it freezing.  Hot water tanks are always full.  No sense paying for gas so turn off.  When draining open hot water taps to let air in.

Answer (score 3):

If your water heater has a drain port that uses a conventional garden hose type fitting, consider to attach a short piece of hose to the port. It can also take a standard washing machine hose. Ensure that you have no pressure, as "almost nonexistent" is still some pressure.

Open the valve for the drain port while the end of the washing machine hose is at the height of the top of the water heater. There should be no water visible when the end is higher. As you lower the end of the hose, you will begin to see water approaching the opening. It will match the level of the water in the tank.

If there is pressure in the system, none of this will work, as the water pressure, even if low, will force water from the tank into the hose, regardless of the level of the hose end.

Comment: I think that this only works if the water heater is higher in elevation than the domestic hot water system or if you have an isolation valve you can close on the outlet side of the water heater. Otherwise, as mentioned in the answer, back pressure from water in the system will force water out of the drain hose.

Comment: Elevation will not matter if there is no pressure on the system at the hot water tank. Any outside source of pressure, including elevation difference, must be nulled in order for this hose method to work.

Comment: All true. But as you noted pressure neutral may be hard to achieve in a domestic hot water system. Just trying to help OP with some info that may help achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

### SHUT THE GAS OFF if water supply is unreliable!

That is to keep the water heater from going into thermal runaway. The heater's design depends on being full of water all the time.

You will need a, how do I put this graciously, a careful and reasonably smart person to relight the gas pilot light (if it's not an ignitor system).

### The water heater is the absolute bottom of your "freeze priority list"

It is the least thing you have to worry about. Why? Because water has incredible "thermal mass", i.e. **it is very hard to change the temperature of water**, it is the highest thermal-mass substance on earth.  That, plus the water heater is extremely well insulated due to Energy Star rules, and, the water is starting at 140F.

Your pool is the second least thing because of the staggering thermal mass in that large body of water. It will not change temperature quickly.  Keep in mind that for water to turn to ice, it must not only get to 32F - it must go through its "latent heat of freezing".  It's complicated.

You have lots of freeze risks - the water pipes.  Focus on them.

Comment: +1.  Also, in a lot of areas, the gas company will come out and re-light a water heater pilot for free if you're not comfortable doing it yourself, since they'd rather do it themselves than have a homeowner accidentally explode.  Of course, how *quickly* they come out when the whole city needs it at once is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation; I have turned both gas water heaters to "pilot" . That is safe as long as there is water in it ; assuming you have the required TP safety valve. . I have two problems ,one heater is in the attic and my wife goes around opening faucets to see if the water is back. She already filled 2 bath tubs when a neighbor told her the town was having trouble maintaining water pressure . Depending which faucets are open ,they may draw water from the attic heater . Also our house is higher than about 80 % of the subdivision. The pilots will help in case we get freezing temperatures again ( the second heater is in a utility room so no freezing problem for it ). And we still have power in the neighborhood !!!